# Ratcoeff but without mixed terms?

Tags: polynomials, maxima

When I have a polynomial in many variables, say

```
p: a*x**2*y**2+b*x^2*y+c*x*y^2+d*x*y+e*x^2+5;
```

then Maxima's output for

```
ratcoeff(p,x,2);
```

is `a*y^2+b*y+e`.

However, I don't want the mixed terms, so the output should be just `e`. Is there a build-in function for this?

I found the assume and declare functions, but don't really understand them. `declare(x,y)` didn't do the trick.

Comment: Well, `ratcoeff` is returning the correct answer in the sense that e.g. `b*y^2` really is a coefficient of `x^2`, so it seems appropriate to carry out some post-processing on the return value to get what you want. Try something like: `foo: ratcoeff (p); terms: args (foo); sublist (terms, lambda ([e], freeof (y, e)));` The key point being `freeof(y, <stuff>)` to tell whether `y` is in `<stuff>` or not.